# Compare 2 cells and index the last cell value

Tags: excel, excel-formula, worksheet-function, vba

I've a 2 sheets.I would like compare A1 of sheet2 with A:A of sheet1 and if it matches then index the value of A1-last row in B1 of 3rd sheet(So I'm stuck with the indexing part that finds the last row value).So this needs to be done for almost 1000 items.So any vba OR formula for this??

[image]

Comment: Quote: "then index the value of A1-last row in B1 of 3rd sheet(So I'm stuck with the indexing part that finds the last row value)" Please make this part more descriptive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, this worked for me for a test just doing the XXX data value. You can modify it for the YYY.

```
 Option Explicit
 Sub CompareAndCopyData()

      Dim DataWorkSheet As Worksheet

      Set DataWorkSheet = ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet

      With DataWorkSheet

           Dim SearchRange As Range
           Set SearchRange = .Range("E2:E5")

           Dim SearchText As String
           SearchText = .Range("E2").Value

           Dim SearchResult As Range
           Set SearchResult = SearchRange.Find(What:=SearchText)

           Dim LastColumn As Long
           LastColumn = .Cells(SearchResult.Row, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column

           .Cells(8, "F").Value = .Cells(SearchResult.Row, LastColumn).Value

      End With

 End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for your help,but I want to index the last value in row #2 (in the above case it is J2)after the match

Comment: @Neelesh what do you want to put as the index? the current date or increment the previous date?

Comment: it need not be the date.it is the value of the last used cell in row#2.So in the picture after XXX is matched with a range it will index the last used cell value(i.e J2) of  row#2

Comment: @Neelesh So you want the value from the last cell in that row to be place in the results section?

Comment: Exactly :) That's all I need

Comment: @Neelish unfortunately I ran out of time. Perhaps @Sixthsense could help. What you need is to set a `Range` to your search area and then from that get the row reference of the found cell. Then use that to do a Last Column check in that row and then copy the data from that last cell to your result section. Fairly easy

Comment: I can find the last cell of a row by formula           '=LOOKUP(2,1/(E2:J2<>""),E2:J2)' but the challenge here is to match E2 with F2:F6 and then apply above formula to lookup for corresponding last cell of that row.